# Continuously exchange data using python-shell

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, stdin

I need to run some python scripts from node. Since my python scripts use complex structures I figured would be better if I only loaded those structures once and then run some the specific scripts (tasks) using the structures.

On node I want to run a script forever (or until I say it can terminate) and keep sending on-demand messages to this script. This script would create a process, using python `multiprocessing`, to run the specific task and start listening again.

A use case would be:

- Node starts, and wakes python script
- Some action on the node client causes it to send a `command` to the python script
- The python script computes what it needs and returns the data

I think `python-shell` can help me with this

On node I have something like this:

```
var app = express();
app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
});

var pyshell = new PythonShell('start.py', options);
pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    handleAnswer(message);
});

pyshell.end(function (err, code, signal) {
    handleEnd(err, code, signal);
});

app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
    pyshell.send('hello');
});
```

My `start.py` script is:

```
import sys

def listen():
    while True:
        command = sys.stdin.readline()
        command = command.split('\n')[0]
        if command:
            print("Received CMD " + command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    listen()
```

I tried the solution on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462072/pythonshell-in-node-nwjs) but gets and error when wrapping the `hello` message in an endpoint.

I properly require `python-shell` module and I'm able to execute a python script and return data (using `print`). My problem is to start the script and send the message after a (random) time period.

When I open `localhost:8000/hello` I get `Error: write after end`

Full error:

```
    Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
    at Socket.write (net.js:717:40)
    at PythonShell.send (C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:206:16)
    at C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\app.js:27:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\leonardo.schettini\Documents\recrutai\client\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I reviewed the wrapper I did for the `python-shell` and found a `pyshell.end(callback)` call right after the script creation.

I was pretty sure the `end` would only be executed when the python script finish, but it happens that it closes the input stream without terminating the script.

Apologies for my lack of attention.